# Viewport Render results from Python

Tags: python, rendering, 3d-view

I have a python script that receives data over a socket and uses that data to update a scene.  The resulting render of that scene then needs to be sent to an output socket.  This needs to occur in real-time (50-60fps)
The viewport render is very fast, and has a high enough quality to work for my needs.
How can I trigger a viewport render from a python script and then access those pixels?

Some things I've tried:

1. calling bpy.ops.render.opengl() from the script.  This is a lot slower than the live viewport render (which surprised me because I thought this was what the viewport was doing)
2. calling bpy.ops.render.render() - even slower
3. calling bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add() and from within the handler, calling offscreen.draw_view3d().  Same problem.
   -- For this one, I would "think" that in the draw handler, the pixels already exist somewhere in the system (and there would be no need to call draw_view3d()).  But, glReadPixels() does not work.

Any other ideas?

I've looked at:
[How to access Render Result pixels from python script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/how-to-access-render-result-pixels-from-python-script)
(the solution for which is not fast enough)

and

[Accessing Viewport Render Result pixels from script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147842/accessing-viewport-render-result-pixels-from-script)
(doesn't have a solution, but what it does have doesn't solve my issue)

and
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html

and reviewed the docs here:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html

In none of these cases have I been able to both (a) render fast enough, and (b) retrieve the pixels

I am open to hacking the blender source code as well, but could use some guidance determining where to begin.

Comment: Have a look to: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule

Comment: Very cool!  will definitely try that out, although I suspect/fear that the render time will be the same as when running python from blender.  Worth a shot though.

Comment: @lemon Do you have any results to share?

Comment: Just discovered this question. I am currently also dealing with this problem and I got at least something working. However, it's not satisfying though. Did you make any progress since you posted here, @EMon? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190140/copy-framebuffer-of-3d-view-into-custom-frame-buffer