# How to force draw_handler_add?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, eevee-render-engine, opengl

I have a draw function inspired from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/231881/131649) answer:

```
def draw():
    print(gpu.state.viewport_get())
    framebuffer = gpu.state.active_framebuffer_get()

    viewport_info = gpu.state.viewport_get()
    width = viewport_info[2]
    height = viewport_info[3]

    framebuffer_image.scale(width, height)
    
    pixelBuffer = framebuffer.read_color(0, 0, width, height, 4, 0, 'FLOAT')
    
    pixelBuffer.dimensions = width * height * 4
    framebuffer_image.pixels.foreach_set(pixelBuffer)
```

and I'm trying to force redraw it once

```
_handle_3d = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'PRE_VIEW')

#some code here to force invoke

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(_handle_3d, 'WINDOW')
```

The reason I'm doing this is because when I use `draw_handler_add` it gives:

[image]

but when I directly use `draw()` it gives the entire window:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`tag_redraw()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.tag_redraw) on all 3D Viewport areas should do the trick. That invokes a redraw.

```
_handle_3d = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'PRE_VIEW')

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        area.tag_redraw()

def remove_handler():
    bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(_handle_3d, 'WINDOW')

# When we remove the handler immediately, Blender had no time
# to invoke the redraw. So we remove the handler with a tiny delay.
bpy.app.timers.register(remove_handler, first_interval = 0.01)
```

When it is just code for your self, no official support needed, you could also use [this trick](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#can-i-redraw-during-script-execution) in the Blender documentation:

```
# Redraw window
bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
```

Comment: didn't work in my case, [here's](https://justpaste.it/2zfoe) the entire code if you want to try it

Comment: Hmm, it seems Blender needs a 'tick of time' after adding the draw handler. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I don't suppose `bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer` invokes the function **while** the script is being executed? Is there any work around that?