# poll() Missing 'window' in context

Tags: python, scripting, gpu, gpu-module

I'm trying to `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` using thread in the following code:

```
import bpy
import gpu,threading

def draw(self, context):

    if self.modal_redraw == True:

        self.framebuffer = gpu.state.active_framebuffer_get()

        self.viewport_info = gpu.state.viewport_get()
        self.width = self.viewport_info[2]
        self.height = self.viewport_info[3]

        self.framebuffer_image.scale(self.width, self.height)
        
        self.pixelBuffer = self.framebuffer.read_color(0, 0, self.width, self.height, 4, 0, 'FLOAT')
        
        self.pixelBuffer.dimensions = self.width * self.height * 4
        self.framebuffer_image.pixels.foreach_set(self.pixelBuffer)

        self.modal_redraw = False


class ModalFramebufferCopy(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_framebuffer_copy"
    bl_label = "Draw 3D View Framebuffer"

    def __init__(self):
        print("Start example code")

        # init variables
        self.width = 32
        self.height = 32
        self.modal_redraw = False
        self.image_name = "color_buffer_copy"
        self.framebuffer = None
        self.viewport_info = None
        self.pixelBuffer = None

        if not self.image_name in bpy.data.images:
            self.framebuffer_image = bpy.data.images.new(self.image_name , 32, 32, float_buffer=True)
        else:
            self.framebuffer_image = bpy.data.images[self.image_name ]


    # 
    def __del__(self):
        print("End example code")


    # modal operator for controlled redraw of the image
    def modal(self, context, event):
        # stop the execution of this example code if 'ESC' is pressed
        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle_3d, 'WINDOW')
            print("Removing draw handler")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        else:
            self.modal_redraw = True

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print("Invoking modal operator")

        self._handle_3d = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (self, context), 'WINDOW', 'PRE_VIEW') 

        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalFramebufferCopy)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalFramebufferCopy)

def invoke_draw():
    bpy.ops.view3d.modal_framebuffer_copy('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    server_thread=threading.Thread(target=invoke_draw)
    server_thread.start()
```

but at the following line

```
bpy.ops.view3d.modal_framebuffer_copy('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

it gives the following error

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.modal_framebuffer_copy.poll()
> Missing 'window' in context

I've desperately tried everything but I'm out of ideas, how do I fix this?

**Edit**
Let me state what I'm trying to achieve.

I have another application which needs the images, so it sends blender a signal to generate the image via servers, which is why I'm using threading in the first place so that listening for signals

i.e. to listen for incoming messages-> move the 3D figure -> generate image

here's the entire [code](https://pastecode.io/s/0pzhkkfi) if you'd like to dive deeper

**Edit 2**
I changed my approach, you can follow it [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274956/how-to-invoke-draw-handler-add-while-running-script)

Comment: I'm not failure with the ops you are using, but have you tried `def invoke_draw(self, context):`

Comment: @Psyonic I don't follow, are you saying I should add `def invoke_draw(self, context)` to `class ModalFramebufferCopy`? if so how do I run it through a thread?

Comment: The word "failure" should have been "familiar" - couldn't edit  
No, the actual `def` at the bottom of your script, change to `def invoke_draw(self, context)`  
But this is just  a guess :) I don't know about multi-threading and I could not find any documentation on `bpy.ops.view3d.modal_framebuffer_copy`

Comment: @Psyonic I don't see how `def invoke_draw(self, context)` would help exactly? it's not a part of the `ModalFramebufferCopy` class so what would I pass as arguments in `threading.Thread(target=invoke_draw)`? also it `modal_framebuffer_copy` isn't inbuilt, I got it from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/231881/131649) answer

Comment: Have you tried overriding the context in `invoke_draw()`  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add/6105#6105

Comment: @Psyonic yep I [tried](https://pastecode.io/s/v6xfie3r) that as well, same error

Comment: When I run that code I don't get any errors ‍♂️

Comment: @Psyonic did it generate the image? it gives the error in the terminal, also I'm using [Blender 3.3.0 - temp-viewport-compositor-merge](https://builder.blender.org/download/experimental/archive/) on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main problem is that you're not allowed to use threading as your way to handle the asyncronous nature of what you're hoping to accomplish. You should rely more on the Modal function and allow blender to take care of the lifecycle of your script.

Something more like this probably accomplishes what you're looking for:

````
import bpy
import gpu

def draw(self, context):
    self.report({"WARNING"}, "Trying to Draw")

    if self.modal_redraw == True:
        self.framebuffer = gpu.state.active_framebuffer_get()

        self.viewport_info = gpu.state.viewport_get()
        self.width = self.viewport_info[2]
        self.height = self.viewport_info[3]

        self.framebuffer_image.scale(self.width, self.height)
        
        self.pixelBuffer = self.framebuffer.read_color(0, 0, self.width, self.height, 4, 0, 'FLOAT')
        
        self.pixelBuffer.dimensions = self.width * self.height * 4
        self.framebuffer_image.pixels.foreach_set(self.pixelBuffer)

        self.modal_redraw = False
        
class ModalFramebufferCopy(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_framebuffer_copy"
    bl_label = "Draw 3D View Framebuffer"

    def __init__(self):
        self.report({"WARNING"}, "Start example code")

        # init variables
        self.width = 32
        self.height = 32
        self.modal_redraw = False
        self.image_name = "color_buffer_cop213521y"
        self.framebuffer = None
        self.viewport_info = None
        self.pixelBuffer = None

        if not self.image_name in bpy.data.images:
            self.framebuffer_image = bpy.data.images.new(self.image_name , 32, 32, float_buffer=True)
        else:
            self.framebuffer_image = bpy.data.images[self.image_name ]

    def modal(self, context, event):
        # stop the execution of this example code if 'ESC' is pressed
        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            self.report({"WARNING"}, "Removing draw handler")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        else:
            self.modal_redraw = True

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.report({"WARNING"}, "Invoking modal operator")
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            # the arguments we pass the the callback
            args = (self, context)
            # Add the region OpenGL drawing callback
            # draw in view space with 'POST_VIEW' and 'PRE_VIEW'
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, args, 'WINDOW', 'PRE_VIEW')

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            
            self.report({'WARNING'}, f"View3D not found, cannot run operator, {context.area.type}")
            return {'CANCELLED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ModalFramebufferCopy.bl_idname, text=ModalFramebufferCopy.bl_label)


# Register and add to the "view" menu (required to also use F3 search "Simple Modal Operator" for quick access).
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalFramebufferCopy)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalFramebufferCopy)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: well I'm not sure this is what I was looking for, I edited the question so you can have a better perception of what I'm trying to achieve